# Values doesn't populate for a drop down in run mode for QTP

Tags: .net, qtp

I am using `QTP 11` with `IE` browser to test an application developed in `. Net`
I have a problem in executing a scenario . My scenario is, I have to select a 'country' and on basis of selection of country, values in 'City' drop down populate.

Now i record this scenario successfully but in run mode, it selects country successfully but cities in 'City'drop down are not populated in 'City' drop down and only default value 'Select'  remains in 'City' drop down.

Hence QTP shows error in run mode.

My code is :

```
Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").WebList("ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainCo_2").Select "Manipur" 'Select Country
Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").WebList("ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainCo_3").Select "Imphal East"  'Select City
Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").WebButton("Save").Click
Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").Link("Logout").Click
```

What is the solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change  your code as below and Try(I have added the code to change ReplayType)

```
 Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
    Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").WebList("ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainCo_2").Select "Manipur" 'Select Country
    Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").WebList("ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainCo_3").Select "Imphal East"  'Select City
    Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").WebButton("Save").Click
    Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").Link("Logout").Click

    Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
```

By changing the **Replaytype** qtp will sync the manual mouse  click .....

Either you can use **fireevent**  like below

**Ex-1:-** B().P().WebList().fireevent "onmouseover"

**Ex-2:-** B().P().WebList().fireevent "onmousedown"   etc..

**Possible Reason for your issue**

Your dropdown might be using a keyboard or mouse event to fire..

Below are couple of mouse events

**onclick** The event occurs when the user clicks on an element

**ondblclick** The event occurs when the user double-clicks on an element

**onmousedown** The event occurs when a user presses a mouse button over an element

**onmousemove** The event occurs when the pointer is moving while it is over an element

**onmouseover** The event occurs when the pointer is moved onto an element

**onmouseout** The event occurs when a user moves the mouse pointer out of an element

**onmouseup** The event occurs when a user releases a mouse button over an element etc...

**Example(MouseEvents)**

1.Copy the below code and Paste it in a test file

1. Save the text file in your preferred location as  **Mouse.htm**(Save as a htm doc)
2. Then open the file in any browser

***Please find the html code in comment section(Unable to paste it here)***

Comment: I have to create event on country line or City line. Can you please write exact code here

Comment: I am still not clear about Fire event . is it firing event on a child drop down when value in parent drop down is selected or else ? And how we can know that our drop down will have which type of event ?

Comment: Code works fine for IE 8 . but i am facing this problem on IE 9.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
  <script>
function Fonmouseover()
{
alert("Action: Mouseover");
} 
function Fonchange ()
{
alert("Action: onchange ");
}
</script><select id="onmouseover" onmouseover="Fonmouseover()"  >
<option value="">onmouseover</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select> <select  id="onchange  " onchange  ="Fonchange ()"  >
<option value="">onchange  </option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select></body></html>

Comment: Copy and paste the above comment and do the stuff(Unable to paste in answersection)

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be a delay is needed between these WebLists... Because if application response is slow it will take time to populate data in the WebList so putting a wait may solve your problem. Thank You

```
Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New   Location").WebList("ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainCo_2").Select "Manipur" 'Select Country

Wait 2 'Or Suitable Time    

Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").WebList("ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainCo_3").Select "Imphal East"  'Select City
Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").WebButton("Save").Click
Browser("AMS | Login").Page("AMS | New Location").Link("Logout").Click
```